# Laravel and vue.js validation

Tags: json, laravel, validation, vue.js

From my Laravel api I receive the following validation errors within json:

```
{
  "error": {
    "billabletime": [
      "The billabletime field is required."
    ],

   "time": [
      "time bust be a integer."
    ]
  }
}
```

So how would I show them in vue.js? Right now I've this but that's obviously not working:

```
 showError (message) {
  swal({
    title: "Fout", 
    text: message.error, 
    type: "error", 
    timer: 2000,
    showConfirmButton: false 
  });
}
```

Comment: You first should use message.error.billabletime in text object

Comment: Yes but billabletime could also be some other error message. (made an edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var errorString = '';
if (message.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
    for(var prop in message.error) {
        if (Array.isArray(prop)) {
            for (var msg in prop) {
                errorString += prop[msg] . '<br/>';
            } 
        } else {
            errorString += message.error[prop] . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Something simple like this should give you the desired result. Not necessary to know index names.

**Edit** added functionality to handle stirng/array